# leaflet markers using search by geojson file

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markers

I have added a search bar in leaflet and I want to search only specific areas for which I have used leaflet control search but the problem is I want the markers on the map for the searched location only on the search not on the load however they are like already available on the map when I open webpage.

I have tried opacity for invisibility and remove layer but nothing works